# libGDX: Get most left coordinate in a FillViewport

Tags: camera, libgdx, coordinates, viewport

How can I get the most left coordinate in a FillViewport?
I already tried things like camera.viewportWidth/50, Math.abs(gameScreen.viewport.getLeftGutterWidth()) but when resizing the game, the sprite which should be left will be outside of the screen.
My resize method:

```
 @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        viewport.update(width,height, true);
    }
```

Comment: `camera.position.x - camera.viewportWidth / 2`

Comment: @Tenfour04  This doesn't work. When making my window smaller it still moves left so it goes outside of the screen. It's because camera.viewportWidth won't change. it's always 1280. And camera.position.x always changes when my character walks. Btw, I use a second SpriteBatch for rendering the Sprite. I did not set his ProjectionMatrix so the cordinates are always the same if the character moves...

Comment: Can you clarify then what you mean by "left coordinate"? The left edge of the viewport in screen coordinates? The expression I gave is always literally the left edge of the viewport in world coordinates, assuming an orthographic camera.

Comment: The left edge of the viewport(in screen coordinates?). So if you resize it, the sprite should always be on the left edge. I don't really know the difference between world coordinates and screen coordinates, but I think world coordinates are the coordinates in the tilemap and screen coordinates are the coordinates for the hud(which can be achieved if you don't set the projectionMatrix?).

Comment: Sounds like you are doing something very complicated with your sprite, trying to draw it with a camera separate from the world's camera. I guess you have to find some way to relate the position and size of one camera to that of the other. I would not attempt something so complicated. Why not just use one camera and move your sprite in the world?

Comment: I only wanted to create a hud... I only have one camera but I use two SpriteBatchs. If I render the sprite with the same SpriteBatch by using the code from your first comment I get the same result. Isn't there an easy way to create a hud?

Comment: Use two cameras and one sprite batch. Draw your HUD in a separate pass. i.e. set game's camera's matrix on the batch, begin batch, draw your game world, end batch, set HUD's camera's matrix on the batch, begin batch, draw HUD, end batch. You can use a separate Viewport class to maintain each camera. call viewport.apply with the appropriate viewport before each pass.

Comment: So there should be two viewports? If I use a FillViewport and a StretchViewport everything is stretched. The gameworld too. If I use viewport.apply() before rendering the gameworld and hudviewport.apply() before rendering the HUD nothing changes.

Comment: You also need to be using the appropriate camera for drawing each. Why don't you start a topic on the libgdx forum...this is kind of an involved question.

Comment: Okay I'm going to create a thread in the libGDX forum.